# Solving Simultaneous Linear Equation using commons-math-2.2.jar from Apache

Tags: java

I am trying to solve linear equation using commons-math-2.2.jar from Apache.

For three small points, i get right result.

When i use following data(big number),i am not getting right result rather i would say result makes no sense;

Following is the code and datas i am using:

```
double [][]matrixPoint= new double[][]{{1,80,6400,512000,4.096*Math.pow(10, 7)},{1,100,10000,1000000,1.0*Math.pow(10, 8)},{1,120,14400,1728000,2.073*Math.pow(10, 8)},{1,160,25600,4096000,6.553*Math.pow(10, 8)},{1,200,40000,8000000,1.6*Math.pow(10, 9)}};
        double [] matrixVector=new double[]{300,350,300,350,250};

RealMatrix coefficients =
                    new Array2DRowRealMatrix(matrixPoint,false);                           
         DecompositionSolver solver = new LUDecompositionImpl(coefficients).getSolver();    
            //  RealVector constants = new ArrayRealVector(new double[] { 1, -2, 1 }, false);
         RealVector constants = new ArrayRealVector(matrixVector, false);
         RealVector solution = solver.solve(constants); 
                System.out.println("The values are:"+Math.round(solution.getEntry(0))+":"+Math.round(solution.getEntry(1))+":"+Math.round(solution.getEntry(2))+":"+Math.round(solution.getEntry(3))+":"+Math.round(solution.getEntry(4)));
```

Is any limitation with the API?If you know any other library for solving the linear equations,please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

What results do you get?

The vector of closest `double`s to the components of the exact solution is

```
[-7680.952380952381,261.8703703703704,-3.102149470899471,1.5775462962962963e-2,-2.9100529100529102e-5]
```

rounding the components yields `[-7681,262,-3,0,0]`. Multiplying that with the original matrix yields

```
[-5921,-11481,-19441,-42561,-75281]
```

which is far off, but that's to be expected, since the rounding errors in the coefficients is far larger than the reciprocals of the corresponding column entries for all but the first coefficient.

Multiplying the matrix with the `double` approximations to the exact solution yields

```
[300.0000000000019,350.00000000000256,300.00000000000335,350.0000000000051,250.0000000000071]
```

which is pretty close.

Solving the system with `double` arithmetic instead of rational arithmetic will probably produce slightly different results, but should be close. The values I got using Gaussian elimination are

```
[-7680.952380952391,261.8703703703705,-3.1021494708994711.577546296296295e-2,-2.9100529100529095e-5]
[299.9999999999927,349.99999999999227,299.99999999998636,349.99999999996,249.9999999999054]
[-1.000444171950221e-11,1.1368683772161603e-13,0.0,-1.3877787807814457e-17,6.776263578034403e-21]
```

for the solution, `matrix × solution` and difference between solution and best approximation to the exact solution.

If the results you get are close to those, the library is working well enough. I suspect the nonsensical result you obtained is solely due to the rounding you did for printing. If not, please update with the `double` results you got from the library.

Comment: Thanks Danial.You are right.Rounding off was giving unexpected result.